# Why does the return statement not print anything to the console?

Tags: java

I Googled it and I didn't hit anything useful, so I decided to ask on here. 
I can't use System.out.println for the project that I am working on, so I used the return statement. Everything compiles just fine, but my return statement doesn't print anything to the console, the program just terminates. All I have in the code is just an if-else statement that returns true or false. Why don't I see anything on the console?
I am using Eclipse Juno's Console by the way.

Comment: Why *would* a return statement print something to the console?

Comment: return is not for printing it is for returning something.

Comment: On some other VM's, I tried the return statement, and it printed what I wanted it to print on the console.

Comment: Return will not print anything to console. Use `System.out` to print or `FileDescriptor.out`

Comment: The return statement prints stuff on JCreator Console though.

Comment: That's cool. Assume that the JVM doesn't do that, though.

Comment: Whats your program? How are you using `System.out.println()` ? It should work for eclipse console.

Comment: For those with a bg in CS this might sound beyond basic. I'm not one of those, so here's my take: To me (take Python in VSCode) , the confusion comes from the different behaviours between running the whole script, where "return" doesn't "print", vs a REPL, where almost everything prints back something. So in a script, place the cursor at, say, a function call line, and press Shift+Enter: this opens up the shell, where you'll see the output printed, whilst Shift+F5, besides running the entire script, won't print anything that's not explicitly meant to be printed, i.e. inside a print statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return just returns a value from a method, it doesn't print it. You'll need to use the `System.out` method or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

At least post your sample code!

Do you mean something like this?

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample sample = new Sample();
        System.out.println(sample.sayHello());

    }

    private String sayHello() {
        return "Hello Java Programmer";
    }
}
```